# iOS reusable and changeable ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating an app to increase my knowledge.
I have a `ViewController` which receives information, and with that information he shows some `Views`. I've already done something like this but in the end that was a mess and had way too much work to change what I've done.

In my attempt I had some views in the same place as others and just changed the `hidden` property to NO if I didn't want them to be visible, at the time that was the best option for my knowledge(4 months of iOS) and I thought to myself that must be other ways and better ones to do this type of `ViewControllers`.

So now comes my question.. What is the best way to do a `ViewController` which can change accordingly to the information he receives??
A base ViewController and the others are subViews from that ViewController??

Example Updated: I can receive N type of news. Some have an image in the top of the view, others have a scrollview like a photogallery to show more than one image, others can have a title with an image and so on.
Others can have text, others one webview to show a video, others can have a collectionView to show some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is have several UIView subclasses. So the setup would look something along the lines of:

- **YourViewController** has a view, that is only there to display **subviews**
- Then depending on the data you receive you instantiate one of your **UIView subclasses** that are made to display the data you need ( *you could also design them in interface builder and access them as a property on your UIViewController* ) and add it as the subview to use
- Whenever the data needs to change again, remove all the subviews and add the newly needed subview.

`ViewController.mainView -> removeAllSubViews -> addNewSubView`

Alternatively you could have multiple view controllers I guess, but it kind of depends all on how and what you need your views to do.

For instance if you need more than just a display of data, and some interaction / manipulation of your data you might want to consider using multiple `ViewControllers`

Comment: I thought about that and seemed a strange way to deal with it, I'm new to the iOS development and this type of programming, thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @MarcoMonsanto Its how I used to do it back in the day, but that was a long time ago. It is a bit hard to suggest a good architecture without knowing what the exact problem you're trying to solve is though -- What kind of data you want to display etc.etc.

Comment: the viewController displays articles, I have 3 type of articles but they use the same labels/textviews/views and some others views exclusive to one type. Should I create 3 different views or there is another possibility?

Comment: It depends on how dynamic your content is. You could also use a webview for news content

Comment: I receive the content in json, imagine this scenario: I have an header which has the section, title, description, a picture, author etc.. In one type i want to show all of these, in another type I don't show the author, with constraints this thing just turns to a mess because I don't want to show that author so I remove that from the view, but I lose constraints and the layout just breaks, you understand what I mean?